# implementing async method wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am implementing async method.But I am not sure that what I am doing is correct.
For example the method writes trace and makes some processing:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Synchronous call");
            if (null == data)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("InvalidInputException");
                OrdersFaultException connEx = new UnknownFaultException();
                throw new FaultException<YnknownFaultException>(connEx);
            }
            try
            {
               object o = await //some call;
               //check that the object is not null and make some processing
            }
}
```

Is it ok? Or I should change it not to have "synchronous" parts
This code is not compiled it is just shows that there parts of code that are "synchronous"

Comment: For one, your code doesn't even compile. What exactly is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have fixed the code so it will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code it's correct nothing will tell you don't do this, but your code `await //some call;` will block the server side execution  but the client will  remain sync with the call  until  the method  server side is terminated or any of  `closeTimeout`            `openTimeout` `receiveTimeout` `sendTimeout` has reach the limit so the call result will be ignored from the client side. 
In order to implements calls  in  async way you should use a tool like [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  that will generate  clientproxy with both `synchronous` and `asynchronous` method signatures.

check the following  link which covers how a client can access a service operation asynchronously    [Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms730059.aspx)

Comment: so why can I write await command.ExecuteScalarAsync(); and here I don`t use await for all function body ,but only for a part of it?

Comment: it's a choice that can be made when an operation can take more time and to avoid that a client using this method will  be blocked for a while

Comment: what is "more time" ?I don`t want the user to be blocked at all.So I need to put everything inside the function into async (lambda) call?

Comment: more time  than expected or a long runing operation so  if you make your call async in  your client side your client can continue to do others tasks while waiting the result from  the server

Comment: please tell me why we are doing await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

Comment: lambda call does not have anything to do with async your code it's ok nothing will tell you don't do  this but I say it's better to do async call  on client side

Comment: can you check the updated question

Comment: I don't  see any  update

Comment: I made other post - sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138488/implementing-async-method-wcf

Comment: instead you can  explain more what you want to achieve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140127/task-based-async-pattern-for-wcf can you take a look